# How can I compute the set of unique characters of a string?

Tags: python, set

E.g. given the string `'Parallel'` I would like to get the set `{'P', 'a', 'e', 'l', 'r'}`

I tried this:

`s = set({'Parallel'})` but it does not compute the correct set.

Comment: post code and not image. also remove `{}` inside the `set()`.

Comment: `print(set('missisippi'))`

Comment: `{"Mississippi"}` created a set with 1 entry: "Mississippi". You then created a second set with `set(...)` which is a set with one entry: the set containing "Mississippi".

Comment: Just an FYI, `set()` is initialized by an iterator. `set("Mississippi")` and `{v for v in "Missippi"}` are equivalent.

Comment: thanks.Now i understand my common mistakes.I just started learning python on udemy and kinda stuck in situations like this a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set function works perfectly. Please check yourself..

```
set('Mississippi')
```

Output:

```
{'M', 'i', 'p', 's'}
```

If you want to preserve the order they appear in your text you can use the OrderedDict

> Code:

```
#import OrrderedDict
from collections import OrderedDict
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys('Mississippi').keys())
```

Output:

```
['M', 'i', 's', 'p']
```

I hope this would be helpful... :)

Comment: The order of the output may vary across computers since sets are unordered.

Comment: sorted(list(set('Mississippi')))    will give it as a list in ordered form

Comment: ```sorted('Mississippi')``` is equivalent and shorter.

Comment: @Leponzo have aded an improved code which will preserve the order they appear in your input text. If your get fine answer please upvote my answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't need curly braces around the word, since that would refer to the unit set `{'Mississippi'}`. Use `set('Mississippi')` to get the distinct letters of the string `'Mississippi'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
word='Missisippi'
a ={x for x in word }
```

Hope it will help you. Enjoy

Comment: It will return {'i', 'M', 'p', 's'} .

Answer (score 1):

What you did was wrong. You actually created a set within a set. Do this
`set("Missisippi")`

Comment: thank you.I did wrote set('Mississippi') at first but it didn't confirm for some reason. So i tried something unnecessary.Thanks for extra info.